# pdf file download in zip file in MVC 4

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, download

I'm working on MVC 4 project. I want to download multiple pdf file in a zip folder. This pdf file are dynamic generated in model popup and select pdf file via check box, after that I clicked on button for download pdf file. How to download pdf file on button click in zip file?

Answer (score 0):

Use [SharpZipLib](http://www.icsharpcode.net/opensource/sharpziplib/) library to Compress files in server. Then send to client.

[This](https://github.com/icsharpcode/SharpZipLib/wiki/Updating) is helps you how to add files to zip.